# Where can I see TFLog output on testflightapp.com?

Tags: iphone, logging, testflight

I'm using `TFLog` in my iPhone app, but where on https://testflightapp.com can I view the output?

Comment: Matt  the reply below should be marked as the answer. it is not fair to those who really are helpful not get the credit they deserve

Comment: Two years later and the answer still hasn't been marked as accepted??

Answer (score 84):

I just found this out by trial and error and a lot of clicking about on the TestFlight site. It's so well buried that I assumed there was no way to view the output yet on their site!

1. Click on Builds and then select the build of your app that you're interested in
2. Click on Sessions in the left-hand sidebar
3. Click the sessions from the user you're interested in
4. Click the "i" information graphic on the right-hand side for the individual session you're interested in
5. Click the Events drop-down on the right of the window that appears and select Log
6. The TFLog output is displayed. Note that it's mixed in with any Checkpoints that have been passed within that session

Comment: yeah that was helpful!! +1  btw this should be marked as the answer

Comment: That's ridiculous. Testflight has some serious usability issues

Comment: Testflight is probably one of the most user-unfriendly sites I've ever seen.

Comment: I have to agree with @moby, would be handy if there was a page dedicated just to viewing logs, rather than click, click, click just to view one.
Apart from that their site is awesome.